# How can I unsubscribe from Firebase onSnapShot in an RTK Query?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, real-time, rtk-query

I'm creating an app in React Native that depends on realtime updates. When a user updates the data in their session, another user needs to immediately see that update without refreshing their app.  I'm using RTK Query to manage my store, but can't figure out how to close the memory leak if I use onSnapShot in my query. Is there another Redux solution I need to consider?

I've tried passing the data through props to manage the data but the management becomes a little complicated when using complex components.

I start with the following in the component but want to move it to the api:

```
export const teamPlayersApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "teamPlayers",
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  tagTypes: ["TeamPlayer"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchTeamPlayersByMatchId: builder.query({
      async queryFn(matchId) {
        let players = [];
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const playersRef = query(
            collection(db, "teamPlayers"),
            where("playerMatchId", "==", matchId)
          );
          //real time update

          onSnapshot(playersRef, (snapshot) => {
            players = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              player: doc.data()
            }));
            resolve({ data: players });
          });
        });
      }
    })
  })
})
```

UPDATE: @phry The below code works, but I don't see a re-render happening when the 'draft' is changed. What fires off a re-render?

```
const {
    data: fetchPlayersData,
    error: fetchPlayersError,
    isFetching: isFetchingPlayers
  } = useFetchTeamPlayersStreambyMatchIdQuery(matchId);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("players changed");
  }, [fetchPlayersData]);
```

...AND IN THE API

```
fetchTeamPlayersStreambyMatchId: builder.query({
      async queryFn(matchId) {
        try {
          const teamPlayersRef = collection(db, "teamPlayers");
          const tpq = query(
            teamPlayersRef,
            where("playerMatchId", "==", matchId)
          );
          const querySnap = await getDocs(tpq);

          let players = [];

          querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
            return players.push({
              id: doc.id,
              player: doc.data()
            });
          });

          return { data: players };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
          return { error: error.message };
        }
      },
      async onCacheEntryAdded(
        matchId,
        { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }
      ) {
        let unsubscribe = () => {};
        try {
          await cacheDataLoaded;
          const playersRef = query(
            collection(db, "teamPlayers"),
            where("playerMatchId", "==", matchId)
          );
          unsubscribe = onSnapshot(playersRef, (snapshot) => {
            players = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              player: doc.data()
            }));

            updateCachedData((draft) => {
              draft = [];
              draft.push(players);
            });
          });
        } catch {}
        await cacheEntryRemoved;
        unsubscribe();
      }
    })
```

Comment: Without any code example of what you are actually doing it's impossible to give you any answer. You could be using `onSnapShot` in dozens different ways here. Please provide actual context when asking a question.

Comment: @phry I'm asking for code. If you're familiar with Firestore realtime db and RTK Query, you'd understand that I can't supply code and that I'm looking for an answer from somebody that may have solved this issue. I'm continuing to research.

Comment: I'm the author of RTK Query, I would say I am "familiar". It is absolutely impossible to answer your question without you giving at least a modified code example of what you are doing.

Comment: @phry I'm sorry if offended you with my comment and I know you are the author of RTK Query. I've seen a number of your posts concerning RTK query and have been very helpful. My focus of the word "familiar" was aimed at Firestore and the realtime solution that RTK Query may or may not be a solution for. I'll rephrase my question so that it is less impossible: "Is it possible to use RTK Query with Firestore realtime database to receive realtime updates through a subscription and then be able to unsubscribe?"

Comment: Yes, by creating that subscription in the cache entry lifecycle - and also by removing it there once a cache entry is removed. If you would finally show code what you tried I could point out how to do it correctly.

Comment: @phry I edited and added the code that I want to move to the api.

Comment: And now please your endpoint definition.

Comment: @phry That's my question. How do I convert that to a RTK Query for realtime data. I attempted it, but couldn't get the snapshot to work. I'll try to reproduce and post later, but I'm essentially asking how to do it.

Comment: Generally I am asking you to show that you at least tried and then share the code that didn't work. I am happy to adjust the code for you so it works in the end, but not sharing any code means you let the internet program for you, and that's not what SO is there for. You write you are already using RTK Query. It cannot be so hard to copy-paste an endpoint definition in here? How can I show you to close the memory leak you seem to be having without you showing the mem leak?

Comment: @phry It's not a simple "copy-paste". I don't keep non-working code in my solution...nor do I check it in to my repository. When I have time to recreate non-working code for a library that may not support Firestore's realtime database, I'll post it. If you want to help at that point, it would be greatly appreciated. The attached code works and is in my solution for the time being. The other 15 api's with working queries are currently great for non-realtime needs.

Comment: I can not pull out code that works for you out of thin air, but in that case please see the documentation on streaming updates.
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates#using-the-oncacheentryadded-lifecycle - instead of a WebSocket, use `onSnapshot`.
In your case, you probably want to combine that with a `queryFn` that either initializes with an empty value or calls `get` once before `onSnapshot` comes into play in the lifecycle method.

Comment: And like I said...when I have time to reproduce the QueryFn with OnSnapShot (in original post)...as stated in my last comment, I'll reach out. To expand on OnSnapShot, it returns an unsubscribe function to be called when we dismount. In my code example, I show you how I use it in my component. I don't see how we can pass that function back to the component that subscribes to the RTK Query so we can call it later when we need it.

Comment: You don't do any of that in your component. Look at the example I linked. It opens a websocket once the first component subscribes to a cache entry, keeps it updated and unsubscribes from the websocket after the cache entry is cache-collected (usually 60 seconds after the last component is done using the cache entry, but you can configure that). As for how a matching `queryFn` would look like, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75338811/2075944 - essentially you combine that with the lifecycle function from the link above.

Comment: As long as your scorecard page is using the `useQuery` hook for that cache entry, your pipe will stay open.

Comment: in order to get the players to return correctly, I have to wrap the onSnapShot in a Promise. However, when I update the data in the db, I see the data in the onsnapshot update telling me the pipe is open, but the screens don't update with the realtime data. Is it the resolve? See attached code in edit above.

Comment: `onSnapshot` does not belong into `queryFn`, but into `onCacheEntryAdded`. I'll answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has two different parts:

- a `queryFn` getting the initial data using `onValue`. This is the point where your query enters a `loading` state and finishes at some point with a first value.
- a `onCacheEntryAdded` lifecycle function that calls `onSnapshot`, updates values and holds the subscription. This is the point where a subscription is generated and your data is updated with new values while your component uses the cache entry.

```js
export const teamPlayersApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "teamPlayers",
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  tagTypes: ["TeamPlayer"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchTeamPlayersByMatchId: builder.query({
      async queryFn(matchId) {
        let players = [];
        return {
          data: await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const playersRef = query(
              collection(db, "teamPlayers"),
              where("playerMatchId", "==", matchId)
            );
            // probably more logic here to get your final shape
            onValue(
              playersRef,
              (snapshot) => resolve(snapshot.toJSON()),
              reject
            );
          }),
        };
      },
      async onCacheEntryAdded(
        matchId,
        { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }
      ) {
        let unsubscribe = () => {};
        try {
          await cacheDataLoaded;
          const playersRef = query(
            collection(db, "teamPlayers"),
            where("playerMatchId", "==", matchId)
          );
          unsubscribe = onSnapshot(playersRef, (snapshot) => {
            players = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              player: doc.data(),
            }));

            updateCachedData((draft) => {
              // or whatever you want to do
              draft.push(players);
            });
          });
        } catch {}
        await cacheEntryRemoved;
        unsubscribe();
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: I'll try to implement this solution and let you know how it goes. This may be worth adding to the documentation as an example. Seeing it in this form makes sense for us newbies. Thank you. I may not get to it as quickly as I'd like. I'm behind about 1.5 weeks trying to figure this out. May have to come back to it.

Comment: Hi @phry, I think I got this working to the point that the data is called with the update, but how do I listen for the changes in the calling component?

Comment: Just use the `useFetchTeamPlayersByMatchIdQuery` hook in your component. That will update every time there is an update.

Comment: I know I'm missing something simple here, but I don't see how the re-render happens. See update in question above. How do I access the updated cached data?

Comment: It's `fetchPlayersData`. Whenever a the cache entry updates, it will rerender your component with a new value for that, because you use the `useQuery` hook and the `useQuery` hook does that.

Comment: I'm not seeing that happen with the code I have posted. fetchPlayersData only updates on the first QueryFn and not with the updateCache.

Comment: Well, the code that does changes in my example there is `// or whatever you want to do` - so I have no idea what you are actually doing. Now it's up to you to debug, as I can't just use a crystal ball. Looking at the Redux devtools: does the store actually change? Calling `console.log` inside that `updateCachedData`: does that get called?

Comment: You're right. No crystal ball anywhere that I know of. I can't mind read. Don't know anybody that can. I'm trying to ask for help so others that are using RTK Query with Firestore can learn from this thread...especially newbies...as there are no other threads anywhere that have breached this use case. I won't ask for your help again. Closed.

Comment: @Sappy3339 my point is that you haven't updated any code examples. You are talking about "my example", but clearly your code has progressed from that, because my example has a *comment* in the update logic. If you want more feedback, at some point you need to provide your state of code, probably in a new question. Going forward with the information currently available in this question *is* divination.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Oren at https://orizens.com/blog/integration-of-firebase-firestore-with-redux-toolkit-query/

The working solution below

```
fetchTeamPlayersStreambyMatchId: builder.query({
      async queryFn(matchId) {
        return { data: null };
      },
      async onCacheEntryAdded(
        matchId,
        { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }
      ) {
        let unsubscribe = () => {};
        try {
          await cacheDataLoaded;
          const playersRef = query(
            collection(db, "teamPlayers"),
            where("playerMatchId", "==", matchId)
          );
          unsubscribe = onSnapshot(playersRef, (snapshot) => {
            updateCachedData((draft) => {
              return snapshot?.docs?.map((doc) => ({
                id: doc.id,
                player: doc.data()
              }));
            });
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("error in players!", error);
          throw new Error("Somehting went wrong with players");
        }
        await cacheEntryRemoved;
        unsubscribe();
      },
      providesTags: ["TeamPlayer"]
    })
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76221482/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).