# About getting data from RTK Query to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, rtk-query

I am currently trying to get data from a Firebase Realtime Database using RTK Query. However, the code here is giving me an error because the value returned in return is not correct. If anyone has knowledge of this, I would appreciate it if you could correct the code to the correct one.

```
import { createApi, fakeBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { onValue, ref } from "firebase/database";
import { db } from "libs/firebase";

export const userApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getUser: builder.query({
      queryFn(uid) {
        try {
          onValue(ref(db, `users/user${uid}`), snapshot => {
            return { data: snapshot.val() };
          });
        } catch (e) {
          return { error: e };
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetUserQuery } = userApi;
```

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { userApi } from "./apiSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [userApi.reducerPath]: userApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(userApi.middleware),
});
```

```
const { data: user, error, isLoading, isSuccess } = useGetUserQuery(1);
console.log(user);
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX1fp.png)

Comment: "the code here is giving me an error" Please edit your question to include the exact error message you get and (if available) the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```js
export const userApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUser: builder.query({
      async queryFn(uid) {
        try {
          const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            onValue(
              ref(db, `users/user${uid}`),
              (snapshot) => resolve(snapshot.toJSON()),
              reject
            )
          );
          return { data };
        } catch (e) {
          return { error: e };
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: Thank you phry!
The userApi error is gone. However, when I checked my browser, I got a new error... I will send you additional details.

Comment: Yeah, there was a missing `toJSON()` call, I adjusted it